# Jackson data-bind deserialization: Skip over an element dependent on a value

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I am using jackson library for deserializing json data.
Is there a way to skip some element if a attribute does not fit a criteria?

For Example

The java classes:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Group
{
   private String name;
   private int id;
   private List<User> userList;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User
{
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private boolean deleted;
}
```

The Json File:

```
["test.Group", {
    "name" : "testgroup1",
    "id" : 3
    "userList" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ 
       ["test.User", {
        "firstName" : "John",
        "lastName"  :  "Doe",
        "deleted"  :  false } ],
       ["test.User", {
        "firstName" : "John",
        "lastName"  :  "Doe",
        "deleted"  :  true } ],
       ["test.User", {
        "firstName" : "John",
        "lastName"  :  "Doe",
        "deleted"  :  false } ] ] ]
}]
```

Usually I am deserialzing like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
test.Group g1 = mapper.readValue(jsonString,test.Group.class);
```

Now, Is it possible to skip every user-element whose attribute "**deleted**" has value **true** ?
I there a way to do this with data-bind or do I have to use another method like tree or streaming ?

**EDIT**

I am developing for android, not desktop.
The reason for this question is, that there can be thousands of User elements and I want to minimize the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Not skipping, but removing after reading using Java 8 (assuming your `User` has a getter for `deleted`):

```
g1.getUserList().removeIf(User::isDeleted);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option. This is done on android and therefore not in java 8. And the reason for this question is, that there can be thousands of Users and I want to limit the memory usage. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject an intermediary by parsing to a tree node and then filtering on the nodes.  An example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Group g = new Group();
    g.setId(1);
    g.setName("Test");

    User u1 = new User();
    u1.setDeleted(false);
    u1.setFirstName("John");
    u1.setLastName("Jones");

    User u2 = new User();
    u2.setDeleted(true);
    u2.setFirstName("Jane");
    u2.setLastName("Jones");

    g.addUser(u1);
    g.addUser(u2);

    try
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonVal = mapper.writeValueAsString(g);
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonVal);

        for (Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = node.fields(); it.hasNext(); ) 
        {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = it.next();
            String key = field.getKey();

            if ("userList".equals(key))
            {                   
                JsonNode users = field.getValue();

                if (users.isArray())
                {
                    for (Iterator<JsonNode> x = users.iterator(); x.hasNext();)
                    {
                        JsonNode entry = x.next();
                        if (entry.get("deleted").asBoolean())
                        {
                            System.out.println("Remove " + entry.get("firstName").asText() + " " + entry.get("lastName").asText());
                            x.remove();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Don't remove " + entry.get("firstName").asText() + " " + entry.get("lastName").asText());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Group grp = mapper.treeToValue(node, Group.class);
        System.out.println("Final group: " + grp);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output results in :

```
Don't remove John Jones
Remove Jane Jones
Final group: Group [name=Test, id=1, userList=[User [firstName=John, lastName=Jones, deleted=false]]]
```

Here is a second approach using a custom deserializer on the Group object.  This is just something I read up on so there may be efficiencies that can be added:

```
public class Answer28536024 {

@JsonDeserialize(using = GroupDeserializer.class)
public static class Group
{
   private String name;
   private int id;
   private List<User> userList;

   public Group()
   {
       userList = new ArrayList<User>();
   }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void addUser(User u)
    {
        userList.add(u);
    }

    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Group [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + ", userList=" + userList
                + "]";
    }      
}

public static class GroupDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Group>
{

    @Override
    public Group deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

        Group group = new Group();
        group.setName(node.get("name").asText());
        group.setId(node.get("id").asInt());


        JsonNode users = node.get("userList");
        if (users.isArray())
        {
            for (JsonNode userNode : users)
            {
                if (!userNode.get("deleted").asBoolean())
                {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setFirstName(userNode.get("firstName").asText());
                    user.setLastName(userNode.get("lastName").asText());
                    user.setDeleted(false);

                    group.addUser(user);
                }
            }
        }

        return group;
    }       
}


public static class User
{
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private boolean deleted;

   public User()
   {

   }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                + ", deleted=" + deleted + "]";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
    Group g = new Group();
    g.setId(1);
    g.setName("Test");

    User u1 = new User();
    u1.setDeleted(false);
    u1.setFirstName("John");
    u1.setLastName("Jones");

    User u2 = new User();
    u2.setDeleted(true);
    u2.setFirstName("Jane");
    u2.setLastName("Jones");

    g.addUser(u1);
    g.addUser(u2);

    try
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String jsonVal = mapper.writeValueAsString(g);
        System.out.println(jsonVal);

        Group grp = mapper.readValue(jsonVal, Group.class);
        System.out.println("Final group: " + grp);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Output for this one:

```
{"name":"Test","id":1,"userList":[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Jones","deleted":false},{"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Jones","deleted":true}]}
Final group: Group [name=Test, id=1, userList=[User [firstName=John, lastName=Jones, deleted=false]]]
```

Comment: Sounds interesting but as far as i know, mapper.readTree will cache the hole Document (or string) as Objects and therefore already use a lot of memory if there are thousands of users ?!? I am not sure about this... I will try it later this day!

Comment: Added a second approach I googled in case it is more beneficial.  Learning new stuff, love it :)